# Google maps distance matrix API: get absolute distance

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I want to calculate distances between two coordinates but sometimes the origin coordinate is over / beyond the destination coordinate. And it is really problematic at one-way roads, because in this case the distance can be eg. 1 km to get back to the destination. In real life it is OK, but actually the real distance is only eg. 10 meters (if I could turn back on one-way roads). So only the direction is wrong.

I can resolve this problem if I call the API twice (`origins=my_origin_coordinate&destinations=my_destination_coordinate` and `origins=my_destination_coordinate&destinations=my_origin_coordinate`).

But is there a easier way to get both distance in one query? (to save my query limit...)

Comment: The distance matrix allows multiple results in a single query. You can do `origins=my_origin_coordinate|my_destination_coordinate&destinations=my_origin_coordinate|my_destination_coordinate` in a single request, which will give you both results.  That won't really help with your quota though as the quota is based on "elements", and whether you do it in one query or two, it will be the same number of "elements".

Comment: Thank you! I think it is the solution, I can select the right distances from the response (from the list of `elements`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance matrix allows multiple results in a single query. You can do `origins=my_origin_coordinate|my_destination_coordinate&desti‌​nations=my_origin_co‌​ordinate|my_destinat‌​ion_coordinate` in a single request, which will give you both results. That won't really help with your quota though as the quota is based on "elements", and whether you do it in one query or two, it will be the same number of "elements".

Comment: Oh, I just realized that your solution takes 4 "elements" from my Google API quota/limitation (because I get a 2x2 matrix). If I use two separate single query (as I wrote in my question) then it takes only 1+1 "elements"...